# How to build output into multiple folders when building with vite and how to change the title for each folder

Tags: javascript, config, vite

When my folder is like below,

```
my-app/ 
├─ package.json 
├─ src/ 
│ ├─ index.html 
│ ├─ main.js 
│ ├─ style.scss
```

Can I set it to build like below?

```
my-app/
├─ package.json
├─ src/
│  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ main.js
│  ├─ style.scss
├─ dist/
│  ├─ assets/
│  │  ├─ main.js
│  │  ├─ style.scss
│  ├─ one/
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  ├─ two/
│  │  ├─ index.html
```

And can I set it differently while building specific text in that folder?

When setting the vite.config.js file as shown below, I was able to confirm that the assets file was also created in each folder.

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  root: './src',
  build: {
    outDir: '../build',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'src/index.html',
      output: [
        {
          name: 'one',
          dir: path.join(__dirname, 'build/one'),
        },
        {
          name: 'two',
          dir: path.join(__dirname, 'build/two'),
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  plugins: [ViteEjsPlugin()],
});
```